# How to make the data row appear right below the header row for hand-held devices

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

[image: shopping]The `<th>` are stacked on top of each other and the `<td>` are also stacked on top of each other. I am trying to alternate `<th>`over `<td>` for mobile devices. Your feedback would be helpful!

confirmation.html

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive-vertical">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th scope="col" data-toggle="true">Venue</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ticket Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Hearing Loop</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for ticket in tickets %}
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th scope="row">{{ticket.venue}}</th>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ticket.quantity}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">$25.00 each</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ticket.loop}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">${{ticket.total | floatformat:2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4" class="text-right">Sales Tax</th>
                        <td class="text-center">${{ticket.tax | floatformat:2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4" class="text-right">Total</span></th>
                        <td class="text-center">${{ticket.total_price | floatformat:2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/edit/{{ticket.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a><a href="/delete/{{ticket.id}}" class="float-right btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
                        <td colspan="4"><a href="/payment" class="float-right btn btn-success">Checkout</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

styles.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;

}




tr {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
}

td:before {
/* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of the technique I typically use for responsive tables. It's written for mobile-first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>

table.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 60em;
}

table.responsive thead {
    display: none;
}
table.responsive tr {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
table.responsive td {
    display: block;
    padding: .75em .375em .75em 6.5em;
}
table.responsive td[data-header]:before {
    content: attr(data-header) " ";
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -6.4em;
    left: -.1em;
    float: left;
    padding-left: .375em;
    max-width: 6em;
}
@media all and (min-width:360px) {
    table.responsive td[data-header*="\20"]:before {
        top: -1em;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width:520px) {
    table.responsive thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
    .responsive>thead th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: .75em .375em;
    }
    table.responsive tr {
        display: table-row;
        border-bottom: 0 none;
    }
    table.responsive td {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: .75em .375em;
    }
    table.responsive td[data-header]:before {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Last Accessed</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-header="Title">Donna's Printing</td>
                <td data-header="Created">5/24/2017 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
                <td data-header="Last Accessed">03/03/2019 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-header="Title">Test batch</td>
                <td data-header="Created">5/24/2017 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
                <td data-header="Last Accessed">03/03/2019 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-header="Title">For Mr. Baker</td>
                <td data-header="Created">5/24/2017 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
                <td data-header="Last Accessed">03/03/2019 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-header="Title">Endorsements</td>
                <td data-header="Created">5/24/2017 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
                <td data-header="Last Accessed">03/03/2019 <span class="time">12:33pm (EDT)</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```